# Executing KW in parallel in robotframework

Tags: robotframework

**Use case**

I have many mobile devices connected , i need to make connection to each devices and open dialer on them and then perform some actions using Appium.

I have keyword which can do this task for me.

for example , i have keyword

**Start dialer on devices**

The limitation is that, this KW will run on each device one by one,
a single device takes approximately 3 minutes.

So if 5 devices are connected , this will be 15 minute task.

is there any way by which i can execute the **KW** in parallel and save some time.

Answer (score 2):

We use pabot for running test suites in parallel which is really helpful:
https://github.com/mkorpela/pabot

You will need to change your command when running Robot Tests to use `pabot` instead of `robot`

Comment: Pabot is used for parallel execution of test cases,not for keywords!!

Comment: Not test cases but test suites, actually!!

Answer (score -1):

There are several async libraries implement for robot framework. Perhaps you can take a look at [Here](https://github.com/Chetic/robotframework-async/) or [Here](https://github.com/awadhn/robotframework-run-keyword-async)

Comment: It would be beneficial if you add simple example usages of these libraries, not only links to them.